# How to fetch list from HashMap <String,List<String>> to another list

Tags: java, android, list, expandablelistview

How to fetch list from HashMap > to another list in Android

Suppose `Hashmap<String, List<String>> myHashMap` has values:

```
{nature2, fruits}
{nature2, vegs}
{nature3, flowers}
```

And,

```
fruits = [apple,grapes,mango]
veges = [potato,beans]
flowers = [rose,lily,lotus,marigold]
```

I have a `List<String> elements`

I want to fetch List from "myHashMap" to elements based on the String id.
Eg.: when I pass id=2, I want to fetch list of 'veges" to "elements" i.e. `elements=[potato,beans]`.

Note: "id" is dynamic. And please don't suggest me to use "int" instead of String in myHashMap.

TIA

Comment: Your problem statement is lacking. What is the connection between `id=2` and `veges`?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, 'id' is the position of string in `myHashMap`. `id=2` should retrieve list mapped with second String in myHashMap. Similarly, `id=1` will retrive list `element=[apple,grapes,mango]`.

Comment: But there is no order to the keys in a HashMap. Also, you have posted an invalid example of a HashMap, having duplicated keys. This in combination with your elliptic mode of expressing your requirement results in an unintelligible question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, then can you please tell me a way to fetch list from `myHashMap` when both key and values are unknown.

Comment: I can tell you any number of ways to fetch a list from your hashmap, each satisfying a different requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use another map like:

```
Map<Integer, String> mymap ...
```

Which will hold your dynamic integer value to actual keys in your existing map like:

```
1, fruits
2, veges
```

And you can do look up something like:

```
myHashMap.get(mymap.get(2));
```

Comment: The idea seems good, but the code will become a bit more complicated. Anyways, I'll try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
Object[] array = myHashMap.keySet().toArray();
Object key = array[ur_id_index];
String value = myHashMap.get(key);
System.out.println("key values=============" + key + " , " + value);
```